# When restoring contents of a partition from a backup, how to only overwrite blocks that are different in backup and current partition contents?

Tags: linux, backup, dd

Usually I would restore partition contents from a backup using `dd of=/dev/where/to/restore` with *incoming stream* from somewhere (like ssh connection).

However, in the case of making a restore to SSD drives known to have severely limited write endurance, that means overwriting the whole drive (in a typical case of the partition(s) placed over the full drive size).
When I look at drive's smart attribute `total_LBA_written` (or equivalent) during a restore of a sparse partition (i.e. containing lots of zeroes), it turns out that even fully zeroed blocks are accounted for in that attribute, meaning they consume flash write cycles as well.

So I'm seeking a way to only overwrite those blocks that are different in the backup stream source and destination drive.
Typical use cases could be:

1. Make a backup, then after a short time with little changes on drive restore it: only a small number of differing blocks would be overwritten.
2. Make `blkdiscard` to the drive, then restore a sparse backup on it: only a small number of non-zero blocks would be overwritten.

I'd prefer not to worry about an FS (or a lack of one) my partitions have.

What tools and in which ways could be used to achieve my goal?

UPD: according to suggestions in the comments, I could try:

1. `rsync` over block device
2. `bscp` utility which does almost the same as `rsync`
3. for `blkdiscard`'ed drives (i.e. containing all zeroes), `dd conv=sparse` could be used.

That all being nice tools and I'm gonna try 'em, however, they are not fulfilling my complete goals: being able to use *streams* (`rsync` and `bscp`) and not only previously zeroed destination drives (`dd conv=sparse`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there anything similar to rsync to syncing block devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344756/is-there-anything-similar-to-rsync-to-syncing-block-devices) `bscp` ( https://bscp-tool.github.io/ ) sounds exactly what you need.

Comment: It's a simple matter of comparing data before writing, easy to script yourself, not sure if there is any standard tool that does it. For the sparse use case there is dd with conv=sparse but it only works if the target device is fully zero.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks for links, I'll try them eventually. However, they basically don't fit my 'receive stream' requirement.

Comment: @frostschutz also thanks for the `conv=sparse`, that would solve 'write only non-zero blocks on a clean drive` part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense; a flash abstraction layer will have to read the data before overwriting it (because the block you write is typically not the same size as the error-correction code block), anyway, so it will from the start not overwrite identical data. Also note that your flash memory probably is quite different from what you think it is – the LBA blocks you see are practically meaningless to the wear-leveling algorithm (which works on internal block sizes and also has to incorporate the storage for the rather complicated error-correction data that you need, anyway) and the actual physical medium.

So, frankly, I'd worry about write cycles as soon as you're doing more full backup restores a week than you'd care to count. You don't seem to.

> I'd prefer not to worry about an FS (or a lack of one)

Well, a Copy-on-write file system with snapshots built-in would solve your issue alltogether. (and again, understands more, but not all, about how the flash memory internally works, so I doubt any clever scheme we'd come up with here would be any better than just CoW/snapshots, which don't ever overwrite data).

Linux comes with such file systems by default.

> my partitions have.

Well, instead of partitions, use LVM thin volumes with snapshots, and "only overwrite changed parts" loses meanings, because instead of overwriting changed parts when restoring a backup, you just forget about the changes in the copy-modify-write copies of the original data. You can also combine external backup storage with that scheme, but working through that would lead too far.

Comment: Just to summarize: I'm aware of the fact that SSD drives are just emulators of block devices, as well as SMR HDD drives are too. However, basing on 'Total_LBA_written' even writing huge amounts of zeros do hurt SSD write endurance (otherwise that attribute would be meaningless?). For typical size of partition ~500G and total non-zero blocks of about 50G, doing `blkdiscard` and writing only non-zero blocks would save about 450G of 'Total_LBA_written' indicator, which *might* have relation to actual flash endurance.

Comment: Regarding using CoW filesystems like OpenZFS and BtrFS and using thin LVM volumes: that all fits only specific OSes (like Linux or *BSD ones), while here I'm talking about generic partition-based backups. For example, I've got a laptop to backup, and it has windоws os on it. I boot it off live linux usb stick and do either backup or restore.

Comment: then, LVM thin is what you want: you can make thin backups of non-thin block devices.

Comment: also "on my laptop, I boot a separate OS" means that, really, you're not doing a hundred restores a week. The wear through your restoration mechanism will be totally negligible. You're worrying too much.