# "rsync --no-whole-file --inplace" wrong total bytes?

Tags: linux, rsync

Running
`rsync -av --no-whole-file --inplace`
gives me
`sent 71 bytes  received 19 bytes  180.00 bytes/sec` 
`total size is 7  speedup is 0.08` 
The source and destination data stores are large and the changes between them were kind of large, certainly larger than 19 bytes, more like megabytes.  
But running `cmp` on source and destination afterwards shows rsync worked and the two files are identical. 
Is there something missing in the rsync's output?

EDIT: something weird is going on. I use a device mapper for both src/dest, and when I reload the destination device it's back to the old version.

Comment: It looks like from this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344756/is-there-anything-similar-to-rsync-to-syncing-block-devices that rsync can work with device mapper devices. Will need to try this. This would explain the behavior seen in the question.

Comment: Would need to see the full command to be able to provide reasonable advice

Comment: It sounds like rsync does not work with block devices. Only with files.

Comment: Duplicate with answer - [Is there anything similar to rsync to syncing block devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701067/100397). Use the answer starting "_Nowadays, rsync supports copying devices…_", or possibly the one starting "_Some versions of rsync have this capability_"